# Add functionality to pop-up modal - Change div structure

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ5mV.png)

I'm a rookie at JavaScript and I'd like to know how to add a function that change the div formation.
The default formation is 3-4-3 (divs formation) and want to add to the popup the funcionality to change formation when is clicked.
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Here's the code:

```
 <section class="line-up">
      <div class="flex-container" id="delantera">
        <div class="caja">
          Caja1
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
          Caja2
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
          Caja3
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container" id="mediocentro">
        <div class="caja">
          Caja1
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
        Caja2
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
         Caja3
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
            Caja3
           </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container" id="defensa">
        <div class="caja">
          Caja1
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
         Caja2
        </div>
        <div class="caja">
         Caja3
        </div>
      </div>  
    
    <div class="flex-container" id="porteria">
        <div class="caja">
          Caja1
        </div>
     
    </div>
        
</section>
<div class="alineacion">
    <button data-open-modal id="cambiar-once" class="btn btn-outline-success my-5 my-sm-0" type="submit">Formación </button>
    <dialog data-modal>
        <form method="dialog">
            
            <button type="submit">3-4-3</button>
        
            <button type="submit">3-5-2</button>
        
            <button type="submit">4-4-3</button>
        
            <button type="submit">5-3-2</button>
        
            <button type="submit">3-6-1</button>
            
        
    </form>
    </dialog>
</div>

<script>
    const openButton = document.querySelector("[data-open-modal]")
    const closeButton = document.querySelector("[data-close-modal]")
    const modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal]")

    openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.showModal()
    })
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.close()
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First solution is for non-dynamic content, second is for dynamic.**

**Non Dynamic Way - using CSS Pseudo-Elements**

- You have 4 containers.
- Upon selecting an option, you remove all child elements from the containers.
- Depending on your choice, you run loops and populate each container with the right amount of boxes **that have the same HTML - not dynamic**.
- Finally, CSS is doing some dynamic work by grabbing the order of each element and applying different `content`. For example numbering (1,2,3...,6).

```js
const layouts = [
  [3, 4, 3, 1],
  [3, 5, 2, 1],
  [4, 4, 3, 0],
  [5, 3, 2, 1],
  [3, 6, 1, 1],
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#controls button');
  buttons.forEach((btn, i) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      setLayout(i);
    });
  });
  // Simulate clicking for first option.
  buttons[0].click()
})

// Function that triggers each layout
const setLayout = (num) => {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.line-up');
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-container');

  // Remove all boxes first!
  containers.forEach(container => {
    while (container.firstChild) {
      container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    }
  });

  switch (num) {
    case 0:
      // Layout 1
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[0][0]; i++) {
        containers[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[0][1]; i++) {
        containers[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[0][2]; i++) {
        containers[2].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[0][3]; i++) {
        containers[3].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      // Layout 2
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[1][0]; i++) {
        containers[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[1][1]; i++) {
        containers[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[1][2]; i++) {
        containers[2].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[1][3]; i++) {
        containers[3].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      // Layout 3
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[2][0]; i++) {
        containers[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[2][1]; i++) {
        containers[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[2][2]; i++) {
        containers[2].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[2][3]; i++) {
        containers[3].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      // Layout 4
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[3][0]; i++) {
        containers[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[3][1]; i++) {
        containers[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[3][2]; i++) {
        containers[2].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[3][3]; i++) {
        containers[3].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      // Layout 5
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[4][0]; i++) {
        containers[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[4][1]; i++) {
        containers[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[4][2]; i++) {
        containers[2].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < layouts[4][3]; i++) {
        containers[3].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="caja">Caja</div>');
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.line-up {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #fafafa, #fff);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.caja {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px #0002;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

#controls {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px #0002;
}

#controls button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc5;
  border: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.flex-container .caja:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: '1';
}

.flex-container .caja:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: '2';
}

.flex-container .caja:nth-child(3)::after {
  content: '3';
}

.flex-container .caja:nth-child(4)::after {
  content: '4';
}

.flex-container .caja:nth-child(5)::after {
  content: '5';
}

.flex-container .caja:nth-child(6)::after {
  content: '6';
}
```

```html
<section class="line-up">
  <div class="flex-container"></div>
  <div class="flex-container"></div>
  <div class="flex-container"></div>
  <div class="flex-container"></div>
</section>
<div id="controls">
  <button>3-4-3-1</button>
  <button>3-5-2-1</button>
  <button>4-4-3</button>
  <button>5-3-2-1</button>
  <button>3-6-1-1</button>
</div>
```

**Updated Dynamic Way:**

This way is for fully dynamic content. No need for pseudo-elements. Every box gets reordered based on your layout options:

```js
const layouts = [
  [3, 4, 3, 1],
  [3, 5, 2, 1],
  [4, 4, 3, 0],
  [5, 3, 2, 1],
  [3, 6, 1, 1],
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#controls button');
  buttons.forEach((btn, i) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      setLayout(i);
    });
  });
  // Simulate clicking for first option.
  buttons[0].click()
})

// Function that triggers each layout
const setLayout = (num) => {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.line-up');
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-container');
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.caja');

  switch (num) {
    case 0:
      // Layout 1
      for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (layouts[0][0] > i) {
          // First container
          containers[0].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[0][0] + layouts[0][1] > i) {
          // Second container
          containers[1].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[0][0] + layouts[0][1] + layouts[0][2] > i) {
          // Third container
          containers[2].append(boxes[i]);
        } else {
          // Fourth container
          containers[3].append(boxes[i]);
        }
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      // Layout 2
      for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (layouts[1][0] > i) {
          // First container
          containers[0].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[1][0] + layouts[1][1] > i) {
          // Second container
          containers[1].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[1][0] + layouts[1][1] + layouts[1][2] > i) {
          // Third container
          containers[2].append(boxes[i]);
        } else {
          // Fourth container
          containers[3].append(boxes[i]);
        }
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      // Layout 3
      for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (layouts[2][0] > i) {
          // First container
          containers[0].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[2][0] + layouts[2][1] > i) {
          // Second container
          containers[1].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[2][0] + layouts[2][1] + layouts[2][2] > i) {
          // Third container
          containers[2].append(boxes[i]);
        } else {
          // Fourth container
          containers[3].append(boxes[i]);
        }
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      // Layout 4
      for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (layouts[3][0] > i) {
          // First container
          containers[0].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[3][0] + layouts[3][1] > i) {
          // Second container
          containers[1].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[3][0] + layouts[3][1] + layouts[3][2] > i) {
          // Third container
          containers[2].append(boxes[i]);
        } else {
          // Fourth container
          containers[3].append(boxes[i]);
        }
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      // Layout 5
      for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (layouts[4][0] > i) {
          // First container
          containers[0].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[4][0] + layouts[4][1] > i) {
          // Second container
          containers[1].append(boxes[i]);
        } else if (layouts[4][0] + layouts[4][1] + layouts[4][2] > i) {
          // Third container
          containers[2].append(boxes[i]);
        } else {
          // Fourth container
          containers[3].append(boxes[i]);
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.line-up {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #fafafa, #fff);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.caja {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px #0002;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

#controls {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  gap: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px #0002;
}

#controls button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc5;
  border: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<section class="line-up">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="caja">Truly</div>
    <div class="caja">Dynamic</div>
    <div class="caja">Changes</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="caja">Every</div>
    <div class="caja">Box</div>
    <div class="caja">Gets</div>
    <div class="caja">Reordered</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="caja">With</div>
    <div class="caja">This</div>
    <div class="caja">Way</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="caja">!</div>
  </div>
</section>
<div id="controls">
  <button>3-4-3-1</button>
  <button>3-5-2-1</button>
  <button>4-4-3</button>
  <button>5-3-2-1</button>
  <button>3-6-1-1</button>
</div>
```